# How to see JavaScript call stack popping from the top

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-chrome-devtools, callstack

I'm studying recursion, and wanted to see how the call stack actually works. I just learned that I can see the call stack piling up in the Chrome Developer Tools - Sources - Call Stack. But when the functions pop, it looks like they pop all at once. I'm hoping to see them actually popping one by one from the top. I feel seeing a visual evidence can really help me understand the concept.

Comment: the reason that happens is because JavaScript blocks while an operation is running. The effect of this is the _appearance_ that everything pops off the stack at once because the UI repaints after all the operations complete. You can see that happen in the timeline view of the dev tools. So, to achieve what you want, you will have to pause the execution at each operation - you can do that with the debugger.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for your comment, but I'm not clear where I should put the debugger to see the call stack popping of from the top. I've tried putting in in the base case and also the recursive case, but it still only shows the call stack piling up and popping all at once.